# Can't fill profile on Careers 2.0

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

I am logged in using OpenId (gmail account). When I try to fill my profile I am redirected to http://careers.stackoverflow.com/cv/create where I see the following message:

> That email address is already registered on another account. You can try logging out and logging back in as the other account, or contact careers@stackoverflow.com to merge your two accounts

When I try fill the field with same mail that I'm logged in with.

Answer (score 5):

Sorry about that, you should be all set now.